# need to run 72 x 24 programs in an AUTOMATIC sequence of events, with each event executing 6 programs in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, command, dos

1. I have to run different programs (72 in number) for each of testinputs (24 in number).
2. I want if i can run 6 programs at one time in parallel for 1 testinput.
3. Further, its needed that automatically it should take over next 6 programs.

   i.e. need to run 72 x 24 programs in an AUTOMATIC sequence of events, with each event executing 6 programs in parallel.

@echo on

```
for /f "tokens=* " %%i in (inputtestfiles.lst) do (        :: i loop iteration (1-24) 
    for /f "tokens=* " %%k in (All_SA_txt.lst) do (        :: k loop iteration (1-12)
        echo %%k
        for /f "tokens=* " %%j in (%%k) do (               :: j loop iteration (1-6)
            echo "%%~dpj" "%%i"
            cd "%%~dpj"
            start /b %%~nj %%i /separate                   :: parallel 6 executions.
            cd ..\..
        )
        pause  :: had to PAUSE, to MANUALLY WAIT FOR 6 PROGRAMS TO FINISH. (LIMITATION)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel has been reported to work on CygWin. So you might want to try something similar to this:

```
parallel -j6 'echo {1}-dpj; cd {1}-dpj; run_program_in_foreground start /b {1}-nj {2} /separate' :::: inputtestfiles.lst All_SA_txt.lst
```

If you get it to work, please comment what the actual command you ran was.